# I want to print these two words from two buttons, but it didn't work as I imagined

Tags: javascript

I want to print these two words called "yes" and "no" by two buttons.

When I clicked the first button to print "yes", the two buttons were covered by the word "yes", I don't how to work it out.

Here is my code and the screen shot:
[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSban.png)
[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jRuk.png)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>example</title>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function yes()
  {
   document.write("YES");
  }
  function no()
  {
   document.write("NO");
  }
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <button type="button" onclick="yes()">print yes</button>
 <button type="button" onclick="no()">print no</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you write document so all content show yes and no , if you want to change specific then use div id or class then update your javascript code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this code. Using document.write() after an HTML document is fully loaded, will delete all existing HTML. if you want to show in same YES or NO in one div then use this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>example</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function yes()
    {
        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = 'YES';
    }
    function no()
    {
        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = 'no';
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content"></div>

<button type="button" onclick="yes()">print yes</button>
<button type="button" onclick="no()">print no</button>

 </body>
 </html>
```

if you want to show in different text in different area

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>example</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function yes()
    {
        document.getElementById("yes").innerHTML = 'YES';
    }
    function no()
    {
        document.getElementById("no").innerHTML = 'no';
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="yes"></div>
 <div id="no"></div>
<button type="button" onclick="yes()">print yes</button>
<button type="button" onclick="no()">print no</button>

 </body>
 </html>
```

for more information

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_write.asp

Comment: I got it,'document.write' can rewrite the whole page.and the 'document.getElementById' can rewrite the element which you chosed.

Answer (score 0):

This because of you are using document.write()  this will override the page. So use div for this propose

Here is the example

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>example</title>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function yes()
  {
   document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML="YES";
  }
  function no()
  {
   document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML="NO";
  }
 </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="myDiv">
    
</div>
 <button type="button" onclick="yes()">print yes</button>
 <button type="button" onclick="no()">print no</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: After looking through your answer, I have a new look about the element about 'document'.

Answer (score 0):

> **why?**
>
> 1. you are using [**`document.write()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write).
> 2. document write is rewrite your whole document just like new page or empty body.and then print with value of the `document.write('value'

)`

If you show with same page declare with some element .and pass the data with element using `innerHTML` .

**Demo**

```js
function yes() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "YES";
}

function no() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "NO";
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="yes()">print yes</button>
<button type="button" onclick="no()">print no</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: so the document is the matter.